# Angular material dialog window does not work properly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

I have a product-item component and I want the dialog to appear when I click on it

In the product-item.ts I pass the MatDialog and then open it with the openDialog function

`<div class="product" (click) = "openDialog()">`

`openDialog(){ this._dialog.open(ItemShowComponent) }`
The problem is that it appears bellow my list of products and I want it to work as a normal dialog(appear above all the elements on the page), How do I fix it?

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUNPW.png)

Woul be glad to get any advice on that

Comment: Please share your code on Stackblitz

Comment: could be a problem with the setup of Angular Material (CSS)
does other Material elements work & look  correctly?

Comment: Also, double-check the z-indexes you use in your custom styles. I think by default overlays are created with z-index of 1000, so if your elements use higher z-index they will cover the overlay, and in return the dialog.